# how can i change upload.php path with login user?

Tags: php

```
  $upload_path = **'./uploads'/**; // The place the files will be uploaded to
```

i want change upload path(corrent: uploads) with login username.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$user = "admin"; //or whatever
$upload_path = "/uploads/" . $user;
```

Comment: $upload_path = './users/'.$_SESSION['user_name'].'/';

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really understand your question, but here is an example

```
$upload_path = './' . ($logged_in ? $username : 'uploads') . '/';
```

Comment: $upload_path = './users/'.$_SESSION['user_name'].'/';